# refer to a non-dependent name without specifying template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

Consider the following:

```
template<typename T> struct Foo {
     typedef void                  NonDependent;
     typedef typename T::Something Dependent;
}
```

I would like to refer to `NonDependent` without specifying any template parameter, as in `Foo::NonDependent`.

I know I can always use a dummy parameter:

```
Foo<WhateverSuits>::NonDependent bla;
```

But that is ugly, and since `NonDependent` is invariant with respect to `T`, I would like to refer to it without relying on the dummy. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: use `void` in place of `NonDependent`

Comment: @Mohit I assume in real code it aliases some other type with a long and ugly name, not `void`.

Comment: I doubt it's possible, but you could add a default value for `T` and do `Foo<>::NonDependent` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not refer to `NonDependent` without specifying template parameter because it may vary or completely absent depending on template parameter. For example:

```
template<> struct Foo<int>
{
   typedef float NonDependent;
};
template<> struct Foo<std::string>
{
   typedef typename std::string::value_type Dependent;
};
```

You may need to move `NonDependent` declaration into base (non-template) struct and refer to it instead:

```
struct FooBase{ typedef void NonDependent; };

template<typename T> struct Foo: public FooBase
{
    typedef typename T::Something Dependent;
};
template<> struct Foo<int>: public FooBase
{
   typedef float NonDependent;
};

FooBase::NonDependent bla;
```

Comment: Oh, I see... Explicit specializations might change the definition of the same name or even remove it.
I like the non-template base solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated this can not be done. Mainly because Foo is not a type available at run-time, rather a template available at compile time, so things like `Foo::NonDependent` are invalid.

In orther to have something available at run time you have to instantiate the template, providing the minimum number of arguments in order to produce a class, of which subtypes can be referred to at run time.